# Does this double negative make any sense?

Tags: grammar, double-negation

Corporate attorney trying to develop a standard form for hiring decisions, with a check mark for me to fill out. Does the second sentence make sense?

____There is a legal basis to not extend offer of employment.

____There is no legal basis to not extend offer of employment.

Comment: It certainly does. There is a legal basis or not.

Comment: It makes sense, but it might be more readable to say something like "There is a legal basis to reject the applicant/There is no legal basis to reject the applicant".

Comment: Both make sense and the check box adds another level of negation, which adds up to three. That seems a lot. In my experience a check box is usually not followed by a negated sentence. The only reason would be the quick overview if all boxes are ticked or not ticked.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, both sentences make sense, although they are written in ["legalese,"](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/legalese) which can make them difficult to understand.

The first,

> There is a legal basis to not extend offer of employment

means there is a legal deficit, conflict of interest, lack of proof of being a member in good standing of the state's Bar Association, record of a felony conviction, or other problem based in law or applicable regulations that keeps the applicant from being considered for employment by your firm.

The second statement,

> There is no legal basis to not extend offer of employment

simply means the opposite of the above: the applicant has no legal or regulatory deficits that would be a basis for not extending an offer of employment *if the applicant is otherwise qualified.*

It is important to note that ***only the first example*** creates any sort of obligation for your firm; i.e., for legal, documentable reasons, you cannot employ the applicant.

The second example only *affirms* that your firm has no basis in law for excluding the applicant from consideration for employment. This does not in any way obligate the firm to hire the applicant, who may be passed over for other perfectly legal reasons, such as the availability of more qualified applicants. As such, the apparent double-negation in the structure of the second example does not exist, although it is understandably confusing.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it's saying that you are forced, legally, to extend the offer of employment, because there is no legal basis for doing otherwise.

When we say that there is "no legal basis" for doing something, we mean that we cannot do it without breaking the law in some way.  It's like saying that there is no legal way to do it.

Whether or not this actually makes sense in context is a different matter.  It's saying that if you didn't offer the person in question a job you'd be breaking the law.  This may or may not be what you intended to say.

I'd also add that this sort of sentence tends to confuse people, or at least make them re-read the sentence a few times to make sure they understood it correctly.

Comment: I disagee that the second choice means that an offer must be extended. It might mean that an offer was not extended for reasons other than one based in legal issues. For example, in some places one has to have attained a certain age to do some jobs because of statute. Not offering a person who has not attained the age would be a legal basis. On the other hand, a person being considered for a job for which all legal requirements are met may not have been offered the job for other reasons in which case not being offered the job may be for reasons not related to laws or regulations.

Comment: @brasshat "there is no legal basis" doesn't simply mean "there is no legal requirement": it means that "it is illegal to do it",  Eg a google search for "there is no legal basis to" reveals *"There is no legal basis to exclude trade in ‘bulk’ fresh water from WTO trade regulation"* or  *"Here, consensus remains an essential element of decisionmaking, as there is no legal basis to make a country accept a proposal against its will"*, or *" The ANC (African National Congress) insists that there is no legal basis to remove President Jacob Zuma from his position"*

Comment: I submit that "there is no legal basis" can mean that an action is illegal in some cases, but in other cases it can.mean that statute and regulation are silent on the mattter.